# WPF UserControl instead of Window in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, user-controls, window

How can I change xaml of MenuManagement from Window to UserControl?

I want to use MenuManagement inside MainWindow xaml lik this:

```
        this.mainViewModel = new MainWindow();
        this.mainViewModel.Show();
        this.mainViewModel.LayoutMain.Navigate(new MenuManagement());
```

but I receive error:
"Additional information: '***.Views.MenuManagement' root element is not valid for navigation."

My MenuViewModel:

```
    class MenuViewModel : ViewModelBase<IMainView>
{
    public MenuViewModel()
        :base(new MenuManagement())
    { //...
}}
```

xaml of MenuManagment

```
<Window x:Class="***.Views.MenuManagement"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
    Title="MenuManagement" Height="720" Width="1280">
<Grid>
   ...
</Grid>
```

MenuManagement

```
    public partial class MenuManagement : Window, IMainView
{
    public MenuManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } }
```

EDIT:
Interface

```
    public interface IView
{
    object DataContext { get; set; }
    void Close();
}

    public interface IMainView : IView
{
    void Show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<Window x:Class="***.Views.MenuManagement"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
    Title="MenuManagement" Height="720" Width="1280">
<Grid>
   ...
</Grid>
```

to:

```
<UserControl x:Class="***.Views.MenuManagement"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
    Title="MenuManagement" Height="720" Width="1280">
    <Grid>
       ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and this:

```
public partial class MenuManagement : Window, IMainView
{
    public MenuManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

to:

```
public partial class MenuManagement : UserControl, IMainView
{
    public MenuManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I receive an error: Error 1 '***.Views.MenuManagement' does not implement interface member '***.Views.ViewInterfaces.IView.Close()' and IMainView.Show()

Comment: @BeataK See update. I removed the interface. If you want it to implement the interface, just add those methods that the interface requires.

Comment: If I will remove interface I receive another error "Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'SafaPOS.WPF.ViewModels.ViewModelBase<***.Views.ViewInterfaces.IMainView>.ViewModelBase(***.Views.ViewInterfaces.IMainView)' has some invalid arguments ". So I need to add those methods that the interfae requires. I hope it will help

Comment: @BeataK, yes, just add the interface back to the UserControl and implement the methods that it is asking for.

Comment: Still I cannot reach the result of all operations which I do in MenuViewModel. The design is now ok, but I need to get to all methods which I have in MenuViewModel...

Comment: I need to do instance of MenuVIewModel, but how after I can insert MenuManagement with result of MenuVIewModel in MainWindow?

Comment: I would need sth like this: this.mainViewModel.LayoutMain.Navigate(new MenuViewModel()); but sth what works.